# Is it safe to cross the Canadian border with a J1 visa and come back on a B1 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, b1-b2-visas, j1-visas

Is it safe to cross the Canadian border with a J1 visa and come back on a B1 visa?
I have heard some stories about having to bring proof that you are leaving the states to your home country after.  Also about people who were told to stay in Canada for a night.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of the question - a visa is a document that allows you to present yourself at a port of entry and seek admission. It is not required to present it on exiting a country. To whom would you do so?

Comment: Hmm, the staying-in-Canada-for-a-night thing may be real: there is a special rule that allows at least J1 holders to do a same-day return to the US without that being counted as an entry to the US, which is probably mainly of relevance to single-entry visa holders. Not sure what happens during the grace period in such a case. Perhaps someone can provide a link to a page stating that all same-day returns US-Canada-US will be counted as not having left the US?

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue to leave on J-1 Visa and re-enter on B-1 visa.

You can review the [J-1 Website from the State Department](http://j1visa.state.gov/) on the subject of 2 year home country waiver.